# ASP.NET Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access EXP_PDF.DLL issue when using DoCmd.OutputTo in PDF format

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, pdf, automation

I've got an ASP.NET application that automates PDF files runtime generation using MS Access.
This solution works fine on Windows Server 2003 with Access 2010 32-bit.

Now I'm upgrading my server to Windows Server 2008 with Access 2010 64-bit. I also tried with Access 2010 32-bit.

Everything works fine except this:

```
oAccess.DoCmd.OutputTo(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcOutputObjectType.acOutputReport,
                   sReport,
                   acFormatPDF, 
                   PDFFile, 
                   moMissing, 
                   moMissing, 
                   moMissing);
```

This line gives me an error that I lead back to the Access run-time error:

```
"Can't save the output data to the file you've selected."
```

This is error only raise when I try to save in PDF format or XPS format. If I change acFormatPDF to acFormatRTF it works fine.
The difference from PDF export and RTF export is that PDF export requires a DLL named EXP_PDF.DLL (I suppose). The DLL is under C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\

Working from Access instead of ASP.NET automation, reports are saved to PDF without any problem.

Running Process Monitor, EXP_PDF.DLL reports a FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS result.

I know this kind of approach is not reccomanded, but in my context, as a temporary solution it makes sense and save me a lot of work.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Since it is a temporary solution could you temporary make a copy of EXP_PDF.DLL just for use by your program?

Comment: I googled your problem and came up with [FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/79122022-c22e-44e6-968e-169f7dbe1eb8/file-locked-with-only-readers?forum=w7itproappcompat) which lead me to [Memory Protection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366786(v=vs.85).aspx). I am not a sysadmin but it looks like a permissions problem and the application pool identity your app is running under does not have permissions to access the C drive.

Comment: @user1378730 ASP.NET application access without any problem C drive. While opening the report with automation, Access even creates a temp.png file under the windows C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ without problems.
I've tried to copy EXP_PDF.DLL to the application foder and system foldere too, but nothing changed. I'm also surprised that removing the EXP_PDF.DLL the error doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem referring to the Microsoft KB 288367 this way:

I opened my Access application on the Windows 2008 Server R2, I opened the VB Editor and then I ran dcomcnfg.exe.

I searched for Microsoft Access Application under the node DCOM Config. I changed the Identity Properties from launching user to This user, specifying a user with all requested permission, such as an administrator user.

Now I can generate PDF files from my ASP.NET page.

[image]